# Help with a footer/header/pagenumbering in a greater project in LaTeX documentclass book

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, books

I just wanna make a nice template for some greater work e.g. thesis. But I have a lot of trouble. I tried to make the pagenumbering start after the table of contents. But for some reason it doesn't worked.

And I tried to make a header who looks like that on this image. [image]

It would be nice with to bold lines where the pagenumber would stay under the first bold line and the chaptername would stay under the other bold line. Further would it be nice if an image, the university logo, would be in the right corner. Would that be possible? Here my LaTeX Code till now.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book} %Dokumenttyp
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} %Seitenaufbau

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zeichensatz
\usepackage[danish]{babel} %Spracheinstellungen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Schriftart


\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, marvosym} %Mathematische Symbole und andere Zeichen (CV)
\usepackage{makeidx} %Um Index zu erstellen
\usepackage{graphicx} %Graphikeinbindung
\pagestyle{empty} %Entfernen von Kopf- und Fußzeilen

\begin{document}

\include{Titelseite}
\include{Impressum}
\include{Abstrakt}
\tableofcontents %Inhaltsangabe
\clearpage %Bereinigt die Seite
\end{document}
```

To make a header I need this code I think:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\includegraphics{IMAGE}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage \hspace{5pt} \leftmark}
```

Please help my anyone. It would be really nice - I don't know how to get further of here.

Kind regards and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, there was no response so far. Are you still interested in solving this matter? If yes, you should make the question more clear. I really don't understand what you desire. If not, a short note qould be nice as well, we can close the question.